# Is there a way to update groups of rows with separate incrementing values in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say you have the following table:

```
Id Index
1  3
1  1
2  1
3  3
1  5
```

what I would like to have is the following:

```
Id Index
1  0
1  1
2  0
3  0
1  2
```

As you might notice, the goal is for every row where Id is the same, to incrementally update the Index column, starting from zero.

Now, I know this is fairly simple with using cursors, but out of curiosity is there a way to do this with single UPDATE query, somehow combining with temp tables, common table expressions or something similar?

Comment: It's possible, but you're missing information.  You're not indicating how the `Index` column impacts the ordering/output of the `Index` column after the update.  You need *something* unique that determines the order in the table that the `Id` column appears in (note that you have multiple values for the `Id` column).

Comment: Same problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957500/tsql-auto-increment-in-an-update-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the you don't really care about the order of the values for the new `index` values.  SQL Server offers updatable CTEs and window functions that do exactly what you want:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as newindex
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set index = newindex;
```

If you want them in a specific order, then you need another column to specify the ordering.  The existing `index` column doesn't work.

Comment: Wow. This "Over ... Partition" clause is really an eye opener.

Answer (score 2):

With `Row_number()` -1 and `CTE` you can write as:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(
Id int,
[Index] int)
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES (1,3),(1,1),(2,1),(3,3),(1,5);

--select * from #temp1;
With CTE as
(
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null))-1 as newindex
    from #temp1 t
)
Update CTE 
set [Index] = newindex;

select * from #temp1;
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KVRXFB63876)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this really, but I had fun figuring it out!
This solution relies on your table having a primary key for the self join... but you could always create an auto inc index if none exists and this is a one off job... This will also have the added benefit of getting you to think about the precise ordering of this you want... as currently there is no way of saying which order [ID] will get [Index] in.

```
UPDATE dbo.Example
SET [Index] = b.newIndex
FROM dbo.Example a
INNER JOIN (
    select 
        z.ID,
        z.[Index],
        (row_number() over (partition by ID order by (select NULL))) as newIndex
    from Example z
) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.[Index]=b.[Index] --Is this a unique self join for your table?.. no PK provided. You might need to make an index first.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this is what you want

```
SELECT *,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY [Index])-1 AS NewIndex FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS Id,3 [Index]
    UNION
    SELECT 1,1
    UNION
    SELECT 2,1
    UNION
    SELECT 3,3
    UNION
    SELECT 1,5
) AS T
```

& the result will come as
 
[image]

Now if you want to update the table then execute this script

```
UPDATE tblname SET Index=RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Id ORDER BY t.[Index])-1 
FROM tblname AS t
```

In case I am missing something or any further assistance is required please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(
Id int,
Value int)

INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES (1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(4,5)


SELECT
Id
,Value 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) Id
FROM #temp1
```

Start with this :)

Gave me results like

Id  Value   Count
1   2   1
1   3   2
1   2   3
1   3   4
1   2   5
1   3   6
1   2   7
1   3   8
2   3   1
2   4   2
2   5   3
2   3   4
2   4   5
2   5   6
2   4   7
2   5   8
2   3   9
2   3   10
3   4   1
4   5   1
4   5   2
4   5   3
4   5   4

Comment: That doesn't work as the last value in the `Id` column in the example would produce incorrect output.  While I would absolutely use the `row_number()` ranking function, it can't be used with the information as presented, `Id` is *not* the ordering critieria (nor is one presented).

Comment: Why not? it gave me results like shown above. I would say that's actually what author was looking for. he would just need to change it a little bit but he got basics.